# How to move tmux window left or right?

Tags: tmux

*My goal*: bind the keys <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+PgUp[PgDn]</kbd> to increase[decrease] current window's index by 1 in TMUX. In order to achieve a behavior similar to browser-like tab moving. Looks like a simple issue, and maybe i over complicate things.

*Problem*: `swap-window` command does not have an `-F` flag option, thus it doesn't recognize tmux formats (expressions)

I've tried:

```bash
user@host ~> # my current window index is 1
user@host ~> tmux display -p '#I'
1
user@host ~> tmux set -F @next_window '#{e|+|:#I,1}'
user@host ~> tmux display -p '#{@next_window}'
2
```

I am trying to use 2 things here:

1. From tmux's [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS):

   > Certain commands accept the -F flag with a format argument.  This is a string which controls the output format of the command. Format variables are enclosed in ‘#{’ and ‘}’, for example ‘#{session_name}’.  The possible variables are listed in the table below, or the name of a tmux option may be used for an option's value. Some variables have a shorter alias such as ‘#S’; ‘##’ is replaced by a single ‘#’, ‘#,’ by a ‘,’ and ‘#}’ by a ‘}’.
2. tmux's [wiki](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Formats#expressions) on expressions. E.g. to substract 5 from 10 in a format you do `#{e|-|:10,5}`

It'll be logical to assume that we just need to add the following to our tmux.conf:

```
# reorder windows
set -f @next_window '#{e|+|:#I,1}'
set -f @previous_window '#{e|-|:#I,1}'
bind C-S-PgUp swap-window -d -t '#{@next_window}'
bind C-S-PgDn swap-window -d -t '#{@previous_window}'
```

However, as i already mentioned `swap-window` does not have an `-F` flag option, so `swap-window -d -t '#{e|-|:#I,1}'` would just produce `can't find session: #{e|-|` and ofc `swap-window -d -t '#{@foo}'` says `can't find session: #{@foo}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me with `tmux 3.3a` (I'm on Mac so not using <kbd>PgUp / PgDn</kbd>)

```
bind -n C-Left  run 'tmux swap-window -d -t #{e|-|:#I,1}'
bind -n C-Right run 'tmux swap-window -d -t #{e|+|:#I,1}'
```